# ubuntu 20.0 grub.cfg is overwritten by rescue cd with older ubuntu version

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, updates

I inherited a ubuntu 20.0 system that the grub.cfg was overwritten by ubuntu 19.4 version (I think).  the original grub.cfg is gone without backing it up.  I see all the files in /boot/vmlinuz* and /boot/initrd*.  I am thinking to boot the system with cd for rescue. go to root filesystem and run
grub-update to update with files under /boot
run grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg to update the file with all the contents of the /boot.
I am not sure if I need to run grub-install.  Am I way off?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Your details are unclear to me; Ubuntu's release format is *year.month* so 20.0 makes no sense; do you mean the 2020-April release version or 20.04 for example?  You've not indicated what type of boot system you use (legacy/BIOS, uEFI etc), but the only way another system would *replace* another in my experience is if you install another system later (ie. installed 19.04 after 20.04, whereby 19.04 takes ownership of boot). Booting your 20.04 system & using `grub-install` is how I'd revert that; but I'm unsure of your situation.

Comment: FYI:   On a *legacy* boot system, the MBR itself (master boot record; or a reserved sector of every disk drive since 1982) gets replaced; each OS using *legacy* boot stores grub stage 0 there; however the `grub.cfg` you mention is stored in the `/boot/grub` directory of the OS itself thus should be unique (executed in later stage of grub). A multi-OS system (like I'm using now) will have multiple `grub.cfg` files (the *noble* system I'm using now has one, another *jammy* or 22.04 system I have has its own) but only one of them is actually used on boot (*usually the last OS installed*)

Comment: Thanks for your input guiverc.  Sorry if I did not mention accurate details.  what I like to go back to is going back to ubuntau-20.04.  system is using UEFI.